# Separation of concern on micro lvl

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The task is to create a DataTable with 1 column + header and 7 rows with content. The content will never change

Implementation:

```
    private DataTable createTable()
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Wochentage", typeof(string)));// Wochentage=> WeekDays

        createRowAndAdd(table, "Montag");
        createRowAndAdd(table, "Dienstag");
        createRowAndAdd(table, "Mittwoch");
        createRowAndAdd(table, "Donnerstag");
        createRowAndAdd(table, "Freitag");
        createRowAndAdd(table, "Samstag");
        createRowAndAdd(table, "Sonntag");

        return table;
    }

    private void createRowAndAdd(DataTable table,string text)
    {
        DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
        newRow[0] = text;
        table.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
```

`createRowAndAdd` does 2 things:

- create a row (and add the text)
- add the row to the Table

Also, my `createTable` does more than just creating the table.

A method should only do one thing, right? How would you improve this and do you think there is a line between clean coding and adding overhead with no need?

**`Wochenuebersicht`**

```
   public class Wochenuebersicht
    {
        public int KW { get; set; }
        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public List<WochenMenu> WochenMenuListe { get; set; }
        public DataTable Gesamt { get; set; }
        public string Wochenangebot { get; set; }

        public Wochenuebersicht()
        {
            DisplayTitle ="Wochenübersicht";
            WochenMenuListe = new List<WochenMenu>();
            WochenMenuListe.Add(createTage());
        }

        private WochenMenu createTage()
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Wochentage", typeof(string)));

            createRowAndAdd(table, "Montag");
            createRowAndAdd(table, "Dienstag");
            createRowAndAdd(table, "Mittwoch");
            createRowAndAdd(table, "Donnerstag");
            createRowAndAdd(table, "Freitag");
            createRowAndAdd(table, "Samstag");
            createRowAndAdd(table, "Sonntag");

            var tage = new WochenMenu();
            tage.MenuWochenDetails = table;

            return tage;
        }

        private void createRowAndAdd(DataTable table,string text)
        {
            DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
            newRow[0] = text;
            table.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
    }
```

**`WochenMenu`**

```
 public class WochenMenu
    {
        private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> data;

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DataTable MenuWochenDetails { get; set; }

        public WochenMenu()
        {
        }

        public WochenMenu(string title, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> data)
        {
            Title = title;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void CreateDataTable()
        {
            if (data == null)
                return;

            var Gesamt = "Gesamt";
            var GesamtAPH = "Gesamt APH";
            MenuWochenDetails = new DataTable();

            // create column header
            foreach (string s in data[0].Keys)
            {
                if (s == KundenTyp.Essen_auf_Raedern.GetStringValue())
                    MenuWochenDetails.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(GesamtAPH));

                MenuWochenDetails.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(s));
            }

            MenuWochenDetails.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Gesamt));


            // Add data to DataTable
            foreach (var dataLine in data)
            {
                DataRow newRow = MenuWochenDetails.NewRow();
                foreach (var item in dataLine.Value)
                {
                    newRow[item.Key] = item.Value;
                }

                newRow[GesamtAPH] = dataLine.Value.Where(dic => dic.Key != KundenTyp.Essen_auf_Raedern.GetStringValue()).Sum(kvp => kvp.Value);

                newRow[Gesamt] = dataLine.Value.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value);
                MenuWochenDetails.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're correct, in general methods should try to do just one thing.

It doesn't seem difficult to alter your code to make that so.

```
private List<string> days = new List<string>()
{
    "Montag",
    "Dienstag",
    "Mittwoch",
    "Donnerstag",
    "Freitag",
    "Samstag",
    "Sonntag"
};

private const string ColumnHeader = "Wochentage";

private DataTable CreateTable()
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(ColumnHeader, typeof(string)));

    foreach(var day in days)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(CreateRow(table, day));
    }

    return table;
}

private DataRow CreateRow(DataTable table,string text)
{
    var row table.NewRow();
    row[0] = text;
    return row
}
```

You'll note I've made some other changes too.

- Refactored your list of days into a, well, list. This lets us iterate over it and reduces duplicate code.
- Removed your magic string "Wochentage" into a const.
- Used `var` when declaring local variables when the right-hand side of declaration makes the type obvious
- Used PascalCase when defining methods (as you should)

An additional change I'd make? I'd make the column header and the days parameters of `CreateTable`. Then you have a more generic function that could be usable elsewhere. I know the data is apparently not going to change, ever, but in the real world you can basically never guarantee that.

Comment: i think your code looks pretty, but is `AddRow` a real useful method?

Comment: i also thought about using `DayOfWeek` to for the iteration would this be an improvement?

Comment: @WiiMaxx it isn't. I was more trying to illustrate that by merging it with `CreateRow` you add a false requirement that the row only have one column. However I agree, AddRow should be removed and the code from there put inside the loop. I shall update my answer.

Comment: @WiiMaxx as for DayOfWeek, I'd actually recommend DateTime's 'ToString("dddd")` method which will output day names localized to the language of the user.

Comment: Here are some more ideas about the issue: 1. Do not use other languages than english in your code. It's good idea to write self-documenting code that works alongside the idea that a method does one thing. 2. The general problem of `createRowAndAdd` is maybe a point of perspective: You could either have two methods: `void AddRow(DataTable table, DataRow row)` and `DataRow CreateRow(string data)` or just use `void AddRow(DataTable table, string data)` - it's obvious you need to create the row. And it's pretty common to use this since the client shouldn't care about the implementation.

Comment: As an argument of this, I'd like to mention collections, e.g. `List<T>.Add` (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646) where adding an element may cause a call to `Array.Resize`. But still the method is called `Add` and not `ResizeIfNecessaryAndAdd`. That's because resizing an array in background is an implementation detail client doesn't care about.

Comment: And going from there, as we declare adding to the table to be an external implementation we shouldn't care about, it would be a good idea to create a static helper with `static void AddRow(DataTable table, string data)` method in order to avoid writing the code over and over again. And then it's just a step to have a `static void AddRow(this DataTable table, string data)` extension method. Although that might not be a great idea in the end due to the dynamicity of `DataTable` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that using a separate function for adding the row is overkill in this particular example.

Generally it may be a good idea, as it allows you to add error checking to the value in future, however in this example, as the values are hard coded, this is not going to be a requirement. As such, you might as well reduce the overhead/complexity:

```
private DataTable createTable()
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Days", typeof(string)));

    table.Rows.Add("Monday");
    table.Rows.Add("Tuesday");
    table.Rows.Add("Wednesday");
    table.Rows.Add("Thursday");
    table.Rows.Add("Friday");
    table.Rows.Add("Saturday");
    table.Rows.Add("Sunday");

    return table;
}
```

NOTE: You can also add an array via `table.Rows.Add(array)` which would reduce the number of calls to Add()

Comment: i settled as useful @nick answer also, but your code is simple. and i believe that simple is the best this condition. right code!